# Change some windows username programmatically (Rename windows user)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-7

How to change windows user name programmatically (using some API or command line tool)
Or how to rename a windows user?

Comment: Why?? this is a typical question! and no resources about it!!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Do you want to log in a different user temporarily?

Comment: No. i need to change the login name or the user name of some specific windows user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the username of a user account with the NetUserSetInfo function.

If you only want to change the username set the level argument to 0 and pass a USER_INFO_0 structure.  You can use a different level if you want to change several things at once.

This is a simple bit of code I've used successfully to change usernames:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <LM.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    USER_INFO_0 ui0;
    NET_API_STATUS result;
    LPWSTR command = GetCommandLineW();
    wchar_t newname[21];

    while (*command != L'*') command++;

    command++;

    ui0.usri0_name = newname;
    wcscpy_s(newname, _countof(newname), L"decommiss-");
    wcscat_s(newname, _countof(newname), command);

    result = NetUserSetInfo(NULL, command, 0, (LPBYTE)&ui0, NULL);

    printf("%u\n", result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is (lm.h) file and is their some alternative of it in .net? because I'm not familiar with c++ :)

Comment: Can't help you there, sorry, but I imagine there is some supported way to call Win32 API functions directly from .net code.  The NetUserSetInfo arguments and the USER_INFO_0 structure are documented in the MSDN library.  NET_API_STATUS is just a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: This question was tagged with C#, yet this is a C++ answer...

Comment: @Herohtar, it's a Windows answer.  We're not here to write people's code for them, after all, but sometimes a bit of sample code can help clarify how an API should be used - in which case it hardly matters what language it is in, does it?

Answer (score 4):

I have written some small method to rename a windows user using System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry class.

```
public bool RenameUser(string oldLoginName, string newLoginName)
{
    bool renamed = false;
    try
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry AD = new
                   DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer"))
        {
            try
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Find(oldLoginName, "user"))
                {
                    if (NewUser != null)
                    {
                        NewUser.Rename(newLoginName);
                        renamed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Log
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //TODO: Log
    }
    return renamed;
}
```

Comment: This is also a useful lick (Rename using WMI, WMIC tool) http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=23638

Comment: Thank you for this! I've managed to reduce your code to `using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry($"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName}/{oldLoginName}")) entry.Rename(newLoginName);` for my purpose and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You can not change obviously the name of the user on Windows system, as it kind of `key` for a lot of internal resources, but you can change `DisplayName` of it, which, by the way, will not affect on internal File structure, so kind of `cosmetic` change. Which most probably will create confusion for you, or for other users on the same machine  along years of use, so I would suggest do not do that. But if you want, here is `powershell` script example, that **should** work for you :

```
  $CurrentUserName = "Your_Domain_Name/Current_User_Name" 
    Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $CurrentUserName  `
    | Set-QADUser -DisplayName "New_User_Name" `
    | FT FirstName, LastName, DisplayName, company
```

For more detailed description look on this good example:

[Change user DisplayName from powershell](http://computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_qad_user.htm)

Note that here they use extraplugin for `PowerShell`.

**EDIT**

another link on subject to clarify what I mean :

[Change user name on Windows7 Professional](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-change-user-name-in-windows-7-professional/d95ddaa7-4235-454e-83d6-77232207c7e2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good answer, but i think you can change the user name programmatically because it can be changed from local users and groups, if you pressed F2!

Comment: ok, but it will not change File system attached to the user in C:\Users\... check my edited post.

Comment: Ok, it's fine..
I need only to change the login name, i'll try it tomorrow :)